# How can I undo changes and retrieve previous form state in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, undo

I am programming a game, in which i sometimes need to undo some steps, is there a direct way to do this?
I tried putting the controls in data structures, stacks and lists and so, but things are too complicated in my game.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "changes" and "form state"? Most likely the answer is in any case that you have to do it yourself.

Comment: When the user in my game changes things, i would like to give him the chance to undo this.
Which means I would like to get the previous state the form was in.

Comment: Still, what "state"? What things are changed? Position? Text? Values? Colors? Sizes? You'll have to save this "state" somehow to be able to go back anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a built-in way to do this; you have to code it yourself.  I would suggest creating a class `FormState` which has members to represent the values of each control on the form whose state you want to save.  Then add methods to copy the form values to and from the form.  Finally, make a stack data structure in your program.  Whenever the user changes something on the form, create a new instance of the `FormState`, call the method to transfer the current form state to the `FormState` object, and push it on the stack.  If the user presses undo, pop the last state off the stack and call the method to restore the form controls from the `FormState` class.  That's really all there is to it.